# jQueryUI Tabs inside jQueryUI Dialog -- how do I get a scrollbar for the tab-content only, rather than the entire dialog box?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tabs, scrollbars

I'm using jQueryUI Tabs inside a jQueryUI Dialog box.  The content in each of the tab panels can be quite large -- for example there can be a table with hundreds of rows inside each individual tab panel.  So scrollbars are required to navigate the content.

By default, the dialog panel displays its own scrollbar -- which is not exactly what I want.  This scrollbar causes the navigation tabs themselves to move up and out of view.  What I'd prefer is for each tab panel to display its own scrollbar if necessary but to leave the navigation tabs visible.  I've tried setting "overflow:hidden" for the dialog panel, and then "overflow:auto" for the individual tab panels (see below).  But then the tab panels are not getting scrollbars even when the content requires it.

Below is a (reduced) test case that shows the problem -- including my attempt to use overflow styles to solve the problem.  Replace "Big content..." with something that causes scrollbars to be required and you'll see it.

Hope that's clear enough.  Any ideas on how to solve this problem?  Many thanks...

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#dialog").dialog({height:300});
   $("#tabs").tabs();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="dialog" style="overflow:hidden;">
      <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#tab-1">tab-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab-2">tab-2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tab-1" style="overflow:auto;">Big content...</div>
        <div id="tab-2" style="overflow:auto;">Big content...</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could limit the height of each div which contains your 'content' ie:

```
height:100px;
overflow:auto;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AeXNP/

Which makes everything very simple.

**Edit**: The harder part comes when (as you requested below) that the content resizes based on the user resizing the dialog. In involves a lot more css... To use overflow in your case, you require a height of the div. As the height is changing all the time, you don't know what height it will be. Therefore you need to manually set a margins and padding so you can set the height to 'auto'. So the css for the self-expanding tab contents is:

```
.fixedSizedTab {
    overflow:auto;     
    position:absolute; 
    height:auto; 
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-top:50px; 
    margin-bottom:10px; 
    margin-right:0px; 
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AeXNP/2/

Comment: That looks pretty good -- but it would be much nicer if the tab height automatically resized with along with the containing dialog box.

Comment: Yes, even better.  That hard-coded margin-top:50px does introduce a dependency on those tabs being a particular height.  At the moment in my actual application they are only 30px.  But I think I can live with that.  Perhaps some javascript could calculate the "real" height of the tabs when the page is first rendered.. but that might be more work than it's worth.

Comment: Ah, found a case where this solution fails -- when the user resizes the dialog, causing the tabs to wrap...

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that. If you give the dialog a minimum width it would restrict the tabs from wrapping. I can't think of another way...

Comment: Strange; it doesn't work for me. I add the class to the div, and this to the css: .fixedSizedTab {
    height: 120px;
    overflow: auto;
}
and it has no effect.

Comment: @Clay - Did you look at my edit? Does the second fiddle work for you?

Comment: @David: Thanks, I'll czech that out when I get home; actually, it probably won't be until Friday night.

Comment: @Clay - It was an edit I made at the time. The fiddle I added at the bottom of the answer works for me so hopefully you can get something useful out of it.